# WF 4.0 persistence extension on Delete

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a need where i need to add and delete some data in a separate database when a workflow starts. I implemented the PersistenceIOParticipant class to add an item when workflow is saved. Now i need some event to tell me when it gets deleted.

Any views on how this can be acheived ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a tracking participant.  The tracking participant will receive lots of tracking records.  The one you care about is the WorkflowInstanceRecord.  You will get a WorkflowInstanceRecord with State="Deleted" and then you can delete your data.

Comment: we are using this approach currently, but since its part of the original transaction, we are always in danger of our data going out of sync, i was looking for a more deterministic approach